# Drush fails with ReflectionException: Class Drush\Sql\Sql7 does not have a constructor

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, centos6, drush

I have followed instructions on http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ to install Drush (tried both global and individual options).

When I cd to the Drupal site root and type "drush status" I get the following:

```
 Drupal version         :  7.34
 Site URI               :  http://default
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  7.0.0
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/site_dev
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

When I type "drush cc all" I get:

```
No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.
'all' cache was cleared.
```

When I type "drush sqlc" I get:

```
exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Drush\Sql\Sql7 does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor      [error]
arguments' in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc:113
Stack trace:
#0 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(113): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#1 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(605): drush_get_class('Drush\Sql\Sql', Array, Array)
#2 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(588): drush_sql_get_version()
#3 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(454): drush_sql_get_class()
#4 [internal function]: drush_sql_cli()
#5 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(368): call_user_func_array('drush_sql_cli', Array)
#6 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(219): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#7 [internal function]: drush_command()
#8 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(187): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#9 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(62): drush_dispatch(Array)
#10 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(70): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#11 /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(11): drush_main()
#12 {main}
```

It strikes me that the problem has something to do with MySQL (because the status doesn't list the DB parameters), but I can't figure it out. Under sites there is only default folder, so it's not a multisite installation.

Can anyone advise what's wrong please?

**UPDATE**
I have upgraded PHP to 5.5.27 and reinstalled Drush 7.0.0.
Following an advice [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125345/drush-was-not-able-to-start-bootstrap-the-drupal-database-mysql-access-denie) I deleted my.cnf from the home folder and after that "drush sqlc" started to work, however when I type "drush -v -d status" it gives me:

```
Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 2.08 MB]                                                                                           [preflight]
Cache HIT cid: 7.0.0-commandfiles-0-81cc86c1995ab7206f383ec28ad43baf [0.01 sec, 2.14 MB]                                                    [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.07 sec, 6.08 MB]                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.08 sec, 6.43 MB]                                                                     [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.34 root directory at /var/www/site_dev [0.08 sec, 6.43 MB]                                                           [notice]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=7) [0.08 sec, 4.48 MB]                                                                                  [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 7.0.0-commandfiles-1-a0882f4af91e1d6b72794cc62bb1b558 [0.08 sec, 4.49 MB]                                                    [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.08 sec, 4.49 MB]                                                                     [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.08 sec, 4.5 MB]                                                                        [notice]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=7) [0.09 sec, 4.5 MB]                                                                                   [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 7.0.0-commandfiles-2-f17fc6bdab2f74278df75194ca483893 [0.09 sec, 4.5 MB]                                                     [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.09 sec, 4.5 MB]                                                             [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 3 (max=7) [0.09 sec, 4.51 MB]                                                                                  [debug]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.09 sec, 4.62 MB]                                                                                                [status]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_CKiVHd --database=site_dev --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_DG1fIs
  1
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.1 sec, 4.62 MB]                                                                  [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.11 sec, 5.13 MB]                                                                      [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 4 (max=7) [0.11 sec, 5.13 MB]                                                                                  [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.11 sec, 5.13 MB]                                                                     [bootstrap]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:38)[warning]
common.inc:698 [0.96 sec, 31.9 МБ]
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Comment: there must be drush version mismatch with that of drupal. drush version 5 works with drupal 7 I guess.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki I don't think so. At least the official website says Drush 7 is compatible with Drupal 7.x

Comment: What happens if you type `drush sqlc` ?

Comment: @ScottAnderson I have added the output of this command to my post. Thanks

Comment: @Alexey how did you go with this, was it related to the issue in my answer?

Comment: What operating system  and version is it? Linux, Windows, OSX?

Comment: @pal4life As you can see from the output of "drush status" above it's Linux. There is also a tag Centos6 in my original post (it's Centos 6.6 to be precise).

Comment: @Alexey As you can see from not having received the satisfying answer yet is one needs to include all the information even though its apparent. Also this is for future benefits that others receive in lieu of folks spending time to solve your problem. :) Also as you can see the flavor of Linux is not apparent.

Comment: The problem is no longer reproduced, as the mentioned bug in [GH #544](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/544) has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it could be this issue: [7.x does not work with PHP 5.3.3](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/544).

There is a solution provided [in this comment](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/544#issuecomment-62539791):

> The base class `SqlVersion` class does not have a constructor and yet an
>   empty array is passed into its descendant (`Sql6` or `Sql7`).
>
> To workaround this, the line:
>
> `return $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs($constructor_args);`
>
> should be replaced with:
>
> ```
> return !empty($constructor_args) ?
> $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs($constructor_args) :
> $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs();
> ```

Alternatively you can upgrade PHP v5.4 or higher.

Or, you can downgrade Drush to 6.x.

Comment: I have applied this patch and "drush sqlc" started to work, however "drush cc all" was still not recognizing Drupal root (as in my original post). I have also tried to downgrade to 6.x, but it was even worse as it failed with "unexpected error" even on "drush status". So I'm guessing PHP 5.3.3 is the culprit, I will try to upgrade it and let you know the result.

Comment: Not sure... But if it was me I would downgrade drush

Comment: Hmm, I've upgraded PHP to the latest 5.5, reinstalled Drush 7.0.0 and now on "drush sqlc" it gives me "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". Though the password in settings.php is correct and Drupal site works just fine. I can also connect with these credentials using "mysql -u dbuser -p". Any ideas?

Comment: Get a connection string using 'drush sql-connect' and try to connect with it from the command line

Comment: also try 'sudo drush sqlc'

Comment: Yes, I can connect with the connection string provided by "drush sql-connect", but when typing "drush sqlc" or "sudo drush sqlc" I get "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Nope, it's alphanumeric. Something to do with the access rights maybe?

Comment: yeah has to be that or file permissions. I've seen file permissions cause MySQL access problems for drush

Comment: drush sqlc works now, see my update above, but "drush status" fails with an unrecoverable error.

Comment: Any fresh ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're running this site in your local (dev) environment (hard to tell from the question ...)

**then** try changing the database host in Drupal's `settings.php` file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1".

Comment: No, the website is running from the live server. Anyway, I tried this and it didn't help. Moreover Drupal stopped working with this setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Windows, you need to verify that your PATH Variable for MYSQL is properly set. I had the problem when I had upgraded my WAMP.

Example like this : `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin`